# checkers pattern

Tags: shaders, procedural

I made a procedural pattern (photo 1) it works perfect on a cube but when i try to get it om my model it gives strange lines (photo 2). What did i do wrong? [image: photo 1]

[image: photo 2]

Comment: Nothing :) Procedural textures are 3Dimensional ... in your case you would have to use 2D texture (image) and use UVmap Texture Coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

The checker pattern is still there, but only in 2D- It's being "projected" from the top, as if it had depth. An alternative would be using UV texture coordinates from a properly unwrapped UV sphere.

Answer (score 1):

A Brick texture is a more convoluted form of a checker texture.

The checker texture works in a simple way:

0. It's black (*Color 2*) in 0 dimensions.
1. In one dimension, it alternates: first it's black for some length $a$, then it's white (*Color 1*) for same offset $a$, then it's black again...
2. In two dimensions, on one axis it alternates exactly as in p. 1. However, it's true only for the distance $a$ on Y axis, and then rather than starting with black, it starts with white. Then after another offset $a$ on the Y axis, it goes back to be like in p. 1... You can think of it, as every 2nd row being inverted.
3. In three dimensions the logic continues: on height $a$ on the Z axis the textures is like in p. 2. Then on the next level for another $a$ distance on the Z axis the colors are flipped.

Here's how the checker texture can be implemented without using the *Checker Texture* node:

[image]

Keep in mind you could keep adding those ÷2 reminders to support 4 and more dimensions. For example, if you use a `#frame` driver, to treat time as a dimension:

[image]

To clear your confusion on why the checker texture looks weird on a sphere, try pressing Numpad digits, or clicking on navigation gizmo to switch to an orthographic view:

[image]

Now from this perspective the texture looks almost correct:

[image]

The reason for this is that now your perspective is almost 2-dimensional - still the surface of the sphere is not at constant X - and the circles between flipped colors denote where the X coordinate of the surface moves past another $a$ offset. You could multiply the X coordinate by 0, to disregard it:

[image]

And as already pointed out by vklidu and SleepyEngi, if your object is UV unwrapped, rather than using (implied) *Generated* coordinate, you can use the UV coordinate:

[image]

In case of a sphere, using polar coordinates will give you a similar effect:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot now I understand better what I am doing :) I just starting with blender I wil try to make this with UV textures.